# defining a simple implicit Arbitary

Tags: unit-testing, scala, generator, implicit, scalacheck

I have a type `Foo` with a constructor that takes an `Int`. How do I define an `implicit` `Arbitrary` for `Foo` to be used with scalacheck?

```
implicit def arbFoo: Arbitrary[Foo] = ???
```

I came up with the following solution, but it's a bit too "manual" and low-level for my taste:

```
val fooGen = for (i <- Gen.choose(Int.MinValue, Int.MaxValue)) yield new Foo(i)

implicit def arbFoo: Arbitrary[Foo] = Arbitrary(fooGen)
```

Ideally, I would want a higher-order function where I just have to plug in an `Int => Foo` function.

---

I managed to cut it down to:

```
implicit def arbFoo = Arbitrary(Gen.resultOf((i: Int) => new Foo(i)))
```

But I still feel like there has got to be a slightly simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the underscore notation instead of defining the whole `Foo`-creating function as `(i: Int) => new Foo(i))`:

```
class Foo(i: Int)

(1 to 3).map(new Foo(_))
```

This works because Scala knows that `Foo` takes an `Int`, and that `map` is mapping over `Int`s, so there's no need to spell it all out explicitly.

So this is a bit shorter:

```
implicit def arbFoo = Arbitrary(Gen.resultOf(new Foo(_)))
```

Comment: Actually, case classes are handled as functions in Scala, so you can write it even simpler: `implicit def arbFoo = Arbitrary(Gen.resultOf(Foo))`.